# GUI Artifacts when trying to run a form from main method in Java

Tags: java, swing

I want to run a form from another package in the default packages main method.

```
// default package
package com.salesmanagement.system

// imported package
import loginForm.*;

// Main class
public class SalesManagementSystem {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Login login = new Login();
    }
}

// the other package
package LoginForm;
import com.salesmanagement.system

public class Login extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form loginForm
     */
    public Login() {
        initComponents();
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        emailtxt.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0,0,0,1));
        passwordtxt.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0,0,0,1));
    }
}
```

when I run the form from the default package main method I will have UI artifacts:
[running the code from the main method of default package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fnp7Y.png)

when I set the `loginForum` package as the main class it doesn't have any problem:
[running the code from package's main method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkLH9.png)

any idea?

thanks.

Comment: This `setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0,0,0,1));` is suspious - Swing doesn't support alpha based colors, instead, use `Color.BLACK`

Comment: I would also make `setVisible(true);` the last thing you do, in fact, I'd remove it from the constructor and have the caller do it, for example `Login login = new Login(); login.setVisible(true);` as it provides the caller the control

Comment: @MadProgrammer if I change this tho `Color.BLACK` the text field background will not be transparent, I want it to be transparent that is the point, and tried to remove those from the constructor and call it from the main method no luck.

Comment: Not sure why you want the text fields to be be transparent - but you should use `setOpaque` instead, as stated, Swing components can't handle transparent colors - they are either fully opaque or fully transparent, which is controlled via the opaque property

Comment: @MadProgrammer transparent background looks cool and more modern, anyway thanks for your suggestion man.

Comment: But you seem to be placing it over a white background, so not really seeing the difference  ‍♂️ . As a user, I’d prefer to see common over cool, but that’s me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swing components do not support alpha based colors, a Swing component is either full opaque or fully transparent.

You should be using `setOpaque(false)` over `setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0,0,0,1))`

I would also recommend against extending directly from `JFrame`, it's locking you into a single use case.  You should also avoid calling `setVisible` in the constructor, this is generally consider a "side effect" and isn't something you always want do.  Instead, allow the caller to decide when it's best to do this.

As a side note, updating the UI update it's been made visible will require you to call `revalidate` and `repaint` to ensure that a new layout and paint pass are executed, which is why I suggest not doing it in the constructor.

Also, beware, not all look and feels may support setting a text component to transparent (they may choose to ignore it) and getting around this won't be easy.

If you prefer to support translucent backgrounds, then you're going to need to fake it, for example...

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    frame.add(new TestPane());
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() throws IOException {
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(32, 32, 32, 32));
            FancyPancyTextField tf = new FancyPancyTextField();
            tf.setColumns(20);
            tf.setText("This is some text");

            JSlider slider = new JSlider(0, 100, 100);

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            add(tf, gbc);
            add(slider, gbc);

            slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                    float value = (float)slider.getValue() / 100f;
                    tf.setAlpha(value);
                }
            });
        }

    }

    public class FancyPancyTextField extends JTextField {

        private float alpha = 1;
        private Color desiredBackgroundColor;

        public FancyPancyTextField() {
            setOpaque(false);
            desiredBackgroundColor = getBackground();
            setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new LineBorder(Color.LIGHT_GRAY), new EmptyBorder(2, 2, 2, 2)));
        }

        public void setAlpha(float alpha) {
            if (alpha == this.alpha) {
                return;
            }
            this.alpha = alpha;
            Color background = getBackground();
            desiredBackgroundColor = new Color(
                    background.getRed(), 
                    background.getGreen(), 
                    background.getBlue(), 
                    (int)(255 * alpha)
            );
            repaint();
        }

        public float getAlpha() {
            return alpha;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(desiredBackgroundColor);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

Now, please beware, "user acceptance" is a hard thing to achieve.  Users don't care about what you think is "cool", they care about how easy your UI is to use.  Spend more time focusing on making your interface intuitive, easy to understand and navigable, users will find that more "cool" then most of what you "visually" consider cool.

Comment: Thanks for your time and your well-made explanation bro.